# PHP if null echo else echo

Tags: php

Not sure what im doing wrong here, but the out come is always null. The script should output "you did not select an answer" only if no answer was selected but otherwise it should output the answer given:

I have updated the script as mentioned but still getting the empty output even when answer is given :/

Thanks for all the help so far guys, but even the below code doesnt work, it now just outputs as blank if no anwser, but if you do fill it in, it correctly echos the answer.

```
if (empty( $a1 )) {
echo"<li>\n<h2>1. " . $q1[0] . "</h2>\n"
    . "<p>You did not select an answer</p>\n"
    . "</li>\n";

}

else {

echo"<li>\n<h2>1. " . $q1[0] . "</h2>\n"
    . "<p><strong>" . $q1[$a1] . ":</strong></p>\n"
    . "<p>" . $r1[$a1] . "</p>\n"
    . "</li>\n";

}
```

Completely forgot to show this part!!

```
// get local copies of single answers
$a1 = trim(isset($_POST['a1'])?$_POST['a1']:99);
$a3 = trim(isset($_POST['a3'])?$_POST['a3']:99);
$a4 = trim(isset($_POST['a4'])?$_POST['a4']:99);
$a5 = trim(isset($_POST['a5'])?$_POST['a5']:99);
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `if($a1 == null)` use `if(empty($a1))` or `if(isset($a1))`

Comment: Of course, that is why I said `OR` but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: See edited question above, still no joy, must be something else, maybe in my answers array?

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is not `null`

```
    $a1 = '';
    if ($a1 == null)   // is wrong
```

should be

```
$a1 = '';
if ($a1 === '')
```

or

```
if (empty($a1))
```

Comment: `$a = '';` does equal `null` when not using strict comparisons

Comment: Updated but still getting the empty output when selecting an answer

Comment: If there is no output then look for syntax errors in your remaining part of code.

Answer (score 0):

an empty is not the same as null try

`if ($a === '')` this respects also the type which is better for code quality

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty( $a1 )) {
    echo"<li>\n<h2>1. " . $q1[0] . "</h2>\n"
    . "<p>You did not select an answer</p>\n"
    . "</li>\n";
}
else {
    echo"<li>\n<h2>1. " . $q1[0] . "</h2>\n"
    . "<p><strong>" . $q1[$a1] . ":</strong></p>\n"
    . "<p>" . $r1[$a1] . "</p>\n"
    . "</li>\n";
}
```

Use `empty` instead of `null` checking

Answer (score 0):

'null' is not same as false or ''.'null' is an object.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, empty string ($a) & empty array ($b) will return true if you test following express:

> $a = ''; $b = array();
>
> $a == null -> TRUE $b == null -> TRUE
>
> also,
>
> $a == 0 -> TRUE

So you should use '===' to test, or there's always unexpected result in your code.